# Issue when using a variable in with_fileglob

Tags: ansible

I have a role with a `files` folder, which contains some packages. And I want to find specific packages in it, for example: `libvirt-clients_8.0.0-1ubuntu7.1~cloud0_amd64.deb`

I tried this and it returns the file name correctly:

```yaml
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: item
  with_fileglob: "files/libvirt*"
```

But if I use a variable for package name:

```yaml
libvirt_package_name:
  - libvirt-clients
  - libvirt-daemon
  - ...
```

And then pass the taks:

```yaml
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: item
  with_fileglob: "files/{{ libvirt_package_name }}*"
```

It will result in the error:

> The error was: error: bad character range. fatal: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution."}

Comment: `libvirt_package_name` is a list, you cannot expand it there, like that, it results in `files/['libvirt-clients', 'libvirt-daemon']*`, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for you explanation. But I still don't know how to get each file in this case

Answer (score 0):

The issue is possibly caused by an invalid operation between two different types. Here,

- The `libvirt_package_name` is a list variable
- And, the `"files/"` is a string constant

You can not perform the string concatenation operation between these two types, you have to use `join` filter. The `join` filter will concatenate the elements of the `libvirt_package_name` list with the `"files/"` string.

**You can do something like the following:**

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: item
  with_fileglob: "files/{{ libvirt_package_name | join('files/') }}*"
```

> The `join` filter in Ansible is used to concatenate a list of strings
> into a single string, with a delimiter in between each element.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried and it returns nothing but this warning: 

[WARNING]: Unable to find 'files/libvirt0files/libvirt-clientsfiles/libvirt-daemonfiles/libvirt-daemon-config-networkfiles/libvirt-daemon-config-nwfilterfiles/libvirt-daemon-driver-qemufiles/libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbdfiles/libvirt-daemon-systemfiles/libvirt-daemon-system-systemdfiles' in expected paths (use -vvvvv to see paths)

Answer (score 0):

Since [the `fileglob` lookup can be a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html#examples), you can use the filters [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/product_filter.html), [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) and [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.join) in order to recreate a list of path:

```yaml
- files/libvirt-clients*
- files/libvirt-daemon*
- files/...*
```

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: item
  with_fileglob: >-
    {{
      ['files/']
        | product(libvirt_package_name)
        | map('join')
        | product(['*'])
        | map('join')
    }}
  vars:
    libvirt_package_name:
      - libvirt-clients
      - libvirt-daemon
```

This could yield something like:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/files/libvirt-clients_8.0.0_amd64.deb) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: /tmp/files/libvirt-clients_8.0.0_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I ran the playbook with -vvvvv, and it return nothing and this log: looking for "" at "/tmp/playbook/roles/libvirt-patch/files/"

Comment: If you do have `libvirt-patch/files` and not `files/libvirt-patch`, that means you made your product the wrong way around. (i.e. `libvirt_package_name | product ( ['files/'])` instead of `['files/'] | product(libvirt_package_name)`). Have you copied the **exact** code present in the `with_fileglob`?

Comment: No, `libvirt-patch` is the role name, inside it is the folder name `files` which contains `libvirt...` files, and I copied your code exactly =)

Comment: Ok, then that means the list `libvirt_package_name` came just with just an empty string..

Comment: yeah, maybe the list was not passed validly..